# Применение групповой политики в текстовой консоли

Tags: windows, консоль, wsus

Добрый день,Есть 100 компов, домен (не AD!). Необходимо всем прописать настройки внутреннего WSUS сервера. Сейчас это делается руками - запускается gpedit.msc и там в компонентах Windows правится.. Есть возможность сделать консольно, но хз как в винде подступиться к этому.

Answer (score 1):

Для применения групповых политик можно пользоваться командой secedit: она позволяет выставлять политики безопасности по заранее заданному шаблону. Также есть возможность писать C/C++ приложения на основе [RSoP WMI Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375082(v=vs.85).aspx).